# Sketch each of the following binary relations in the Cartesian plane and state if it is totally defined, and if it is well-defined :

Tags: relations, order-theory

> Sketch each of the following binary relations in the Cartesian plane and state if it is totally defined, and if it is well-defined:

> (a) the binary relation $H = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}× \mathbb{R}: xy=1 \}$
> on $\mathbb{R}$;

> (b) the binary relation $P$ on $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} × \mathbb{R}$  (where $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ is the set of non-negative real numbers) that is defined by specifying, for any $x \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ and $y \in R$, that $$ x P y \iff x = y^2. $$

I'm given a question like this. What does the term "totally defined" mean? Does it mean total order relation?

And also what is the definition of a relation being "well defined"? I know the definition of a function being well defined but didn't know that any such restrictions were imposed on relation in general.

Please anyone have any idea what these two terms are saying, I'm just stuck there with the terms.

Comment: I understand your confusion. The term ["total relation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_relation) is used, but there are several possible readings (domain includes everything, range includes everything or both). The term "well-defined relation" makes no sense: a relation is just a set of pairs. Where did you find these problems?

Comment: A friend of mine got stuck into these problems. Me being a math major, he sent this to me. But I have never heard of any of these terms and as you said the "well defined relation" doesn't make sense to me either because well definition works for functions only, which is a special type of relation.

Comment: I see. I think your friend will have to take the problems back to where they got them from and say "please explain".

Comment: Yes I already told him so.